# Mongodb duplicate errorr

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
  db.collection("resource").update({name: name}, {
      name: name,
      type: type
  }, {
      upsert: true
    }
```

I differentiate documents by their names. I do not add document if it exists with the same. But I want to warn user by saying "It already exists, operation failed" How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to *insert* documents, not *update or insert* documents.

**1:** Add unique index on `resource.name` ahead of time.

```
db.resouces.createIndex({ name: 1 }, { unique: true })
```

Important: do this once, not on every request.

See [mongodb create index docs](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/tutorial/create-a-unique-index/#unique-index-on-a-single-field).

**2:** Use `insert` instead of `update + upsert`.

It sounds like you want to actually `insert` a document, and get an error if there is a duplicate key.

```
db.resources.insert({ name: "AJ" })  // ok
db.resources.insert({ name: "AJ" })  // error!
```

You will get a duplicate key error on the second insert. Error code `11000`.

See [mongodb docs on insert](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/db.collection.insert/).

**3:** Use promise-try-catch in javascript.

The code to do error checking looks like:

```
var db = require("mongojs")(DATABASE_URL, [ "resources" ])

var duplicateKey = function (err) {
  return err.code == "11000"
}

db.resources.insert({ name: name })
  .then(function () {
    // success!
  })
  .catch(duplicateKey, function () {
    // sorry! name is taken
  })
```

Comment: I know that the second line will throw an error but how can i handle the error? I want to warn user by saying "It already exists, operation failed"